# every second 1 surrounded by 0s, formal regular expression

Tags: regex

I want every second 1 to be surrounded by 0s. I got this far:

```
0* + 0*10* + 0*10+10+
```

which is partially what i want. How do i make sure that every second 1 is surrounded by 0s?

I need to use formal regular expressions.

01010 (second 1 is surrounded by 0s)

0110 (second 1 is NOT surrounded by 0s, not what i want)

Comment: but the second 1 is surrounded by * and 0. Provide more examples.

Comment: Not clear.  Show your sample string and the desired result.

Comment: Also - show what you have done so far so that we can improve your code rather than do your work for you (no offence intended)

Comment: @Bloody which lang or tool you're running?

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern, it fails if any second `1` is not surrounded by `0's`

```
^(?:[^1]*1[^1]*010)*(?:[^1]*1?[^1]*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/179)

OR

```
^(?:[^1]*1[^1]*010)+(?:[^1]*1[^1]*)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/11)

Comment: this matches an empty string. I think op don't want that.

Comment: op is not very clear, looks almost identical to your edited one

Comment: yep, i'll delete mine. And i suggest you to copy my answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, your added pattern fail this input `21201022`

Answer (score 0):

If your input alphabet (which you don't specify) is just `0` and `1` (which it appears to be from your examples), this is mostly just equivalent to saying "No two consecutive `1` characters", since if an odd `1` was adjacent to another `1`, that other `1` would be an even `1` that needs to be surrounded by `0`s and not next to a `1`.  The only other requirement would seem to be "can't end in a `1` if there are an even number of `1`s.

So with that in mind:

```
0*(10+)*  -- no two consecutive 1s, can't end with a 1
```

if you want to allow ending in a `1` as long as there are an odd number of `1`s:

```
0*(10+10+)*1?0*
```

Answer (score 0):

If every second `1` is surrounded by `0`s, you need to find the pattern `010`. Then before that you can have at most one `1`, with any number of zeros.

So to match a string where the second one is surrounded by zeroes, its:

```
(?:10*(010))
```

Then its just a matter of repeating this:

```
(?:10*(010))+
```

If its a matter of other non-`01` characters being included:

```
(?:[^1]*1[^1]*(010))+[^1]*
```

Which is a repeating group of any number of non-1s, a 1, any number of non-1s, then `010`, followed by non-1s.